# Hide one category

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I hide that 'course or call' category from the page..

I have `var_dump` the variable which is passing as parameter to `query_posts`

```
$args = jr_filter_form();
var_dump($args);
query_posts($args);
```

[image]

This category is having `tag_ID="69"` in its url , which I have seen in WordPress dashboard, job category page.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/), it's your friend :)

It is detailed in the [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Exclude_Categories_From_Your_Home_Page)

I would however recommend against using query_posts. [See this for some detail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

[get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) is more likely what you need - and a quick Google will give you [this example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28084/exclude-category-from-get-posts).

Comment: thanks Mark for reply, but i am getting taxonomy=job_type&tag_ID=69&post_type=job_listing in url i just want to hide this tad_ID 69

Comment: use a minus to exclude a category/tag, e.g. tag_ID=-69.

Comment: Is it a tag? - in your original post, you referred to it as a category.

Comment: i mean that category has been assigned a tag_id = 25

Comment: Try query_posts("tag__not_in=x"); where x is your tag ID.